# Ignore submodule dirty status on commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repository with a submodule. For me, this submodule is read-only, so I'm using submodule.Module.ignore=dirty.

This works fine for 'git status', but when I commit, the whole submodule is scanned and in git's comments I can see that it's dirty.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved upstream in commit [8f6811efed5451c72aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f6811efed5451c72aa)

Comment: Nice job tracking that down and fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really never want to see changes to the submodule, you can add a line to .git/info/exclude inside the submodule with a '*' pattern.

This will result in the submodule always reporting itself as clean, regardless of what has changed.

```
echo "*" >> path/to/submodule/.git/info/exclude
```

Comment: You might want to escape that `*` though to prevent shell expansion.

Comment: This helps, but it also prevents seeing the changes from inside the submodule. I just want them ignored externally...

Comment: In newer versions of Git, `path/to/submodule/.git` is a file, and not a directory.

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to edit the `.git/info/exclude` file, to add a pattern to be ignored. But for a submodule, this won't work. Instead, you should edit `.git/submodule_foo/info/exclude`, from the root of the Git repo.

This is because, in newer versions of Git, the path `submodule_foo/.git` is a file, not a directory. Its contents lets us know where the `.git` files for the submodule are:

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/submodule_foo
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. The question was about completely ignoring the internal submodule state while committing in the supermodule.